# Find future events in sqlite3

Tags: events, sqlite, output

I have a calendar of several events happening in a venue. I want the future events to show in my output. 
I have tried to use this code -

```
select * from event where date >= CURRENT_DATE;
```

I get both future and past events when use this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is date and CURRENT_DATE a timestamp?

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `date` column?

Comment: I have used date TEXT '18.06.15'
(as an example)